# Wget not downloading images in recursive download

Tags: wget

I used this command to download a webpage recursively in 5 levels to navigate it offline:

```
wget -r -p --convert-links http://www.pythondiario.com
```

But the images are not downloaded properly.

How do I fix this?

Comment: This doesn't work because the images on the site you mention are hosted on a different site.

Comment: Ok, so how can I fix this?

Comment: You use some other tool to mirror the site.

Comment: Thanks to your explanation of my problem, I found a way to solve my problem using wget. If anyone has the same problem, here is the solution: Use the "-H" command to allow the download of files from different domains

Answer (score 8):

As [Satō Katsura](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117516/sat%c5%8d-katsura) noted in a comment, some images on this page are on a different host. By default, wget does not follow cross-host links (this applies to image retrieval as well as recursive traversal).

To make wget follow cross-host links, pass the `-H` option. It is recommended to pass the `-D` option as well to limit which hosts are traversed, otherwise you risk downloading a lot of linked content.

```
wget -r -p --convert-links -H -Dblogspot.com http://www.pythondiario.com
```

Note that `-H` and `-D` apply to recursive traversal as well as images. You can further restrict cross-host links by adding `-R` or `--reject-regex` options.

See [“spanning hosts” in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Spanning-Hosts) for more details.